# Raise different frames using a button, depending on radiobuttons value

Tags: python, tkinter

Let me preface this with saying that I'm relatively new to Python, so my script may not be very pythonic- apologies for this!

In any case, I repurposed some code so that I currently have a start page with a number of radiobuttons (page 1, page 2,....page 6), a quit button and a next button. I want to be able to select one of the radiobuttons and then press the 'next' button to get to the page dictated by the selected radiobutton. The code has been stripped out of PageOne() etc to be concise.

The other QA's I've looked at involved linking a function to a button but not how to make the function depend on other inputs.

Currently I'm getting the error

```
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'PageSelection'
```

---

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

LARGE_FONT = ('Verdana', 12)
NORM_FONT = ('Verdana', 10)
SMALL_FONT = ('Verdana', 8)    

class PageSelectionWiz(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default="icon.ico")
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Page Selector")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo, PageThree, PageFour, PageFive, PageSix):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew',padx=20, pady=20)
        self.ShowFrame(StartPage)

    def ShowFrame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def PageSelection(self, controller, page_val):
        page_choice = page_val.get()
        if page_choice == 1:
            controller.ShowFrame(PageOne)
        elif page_choice == 2:
            controller.ShowFrame(PageTwo)
        elif page_choice == 3:
            controller.ShowFrame(PageThree)
        elif page_choice == 4:
            controller.ShowFrame(PageFour)
        elif page_choice == 5:
            controller.ShowFrame(PageFive)
        else:
            controller.ShowFrame(PageSix)

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text='Page Selection', font='LARGE_FONT')
        description = ttk.Label(self, text='Please select a page:')
        label.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky='w',padx=20, pady=5, columnspan=2)
        description.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='w', padx=20, pady=5, columnspan=2)

        page_val = tk.IntVar()

        rad_button1 = ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='Page 1', value=1, variable=page_val)
        rad_button1.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky='sw')
        rad_button2 = ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='Page 2', value=2, variable=page_val)
        rad_button2.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky='sw')
        rad_button3 = ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='Page 3', value=3, variable=page_val)
        rad_button3.grid(row=5, column=2, sticky='sw')
        rad_button4 = ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='Page 4', value=4, variable=page_val)
        rad_button4.grid(row=6, column=2, sticky='sw')
        rad_button5 = ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='Page 5', value=5, variable=page_val)
        rad_button5.grid(row=7, column=2, sticky='sw')
        rad_button6 = ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='Page 6', value=6, variable=page_val)
        rad_button6.grid(row=8, column=2, sticky='sw')

        col_pad = ttk.Label(self, text='').grid(row=9, column=3, pady=25, padx=25)

        quit_button= ttk.Button(self, text='Quit', command=quit)
        quit_button.grid(row=10, column=4, sticky='e')

        nxt = ttk.Button(self, text='Next >', command=lambda: PageSelection(page_val))
        nxt.grid(row=10,column=5, sticky='w')


class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

class PageThree(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)


class PageFour(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

class PageFive(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)


class PageSix(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

app = PageSelectionWiz()
app.geometry('640x480-8-8')
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was on this line:

```py
nxt = ttk.Button(self, text='Next >', command = lambda:self.PageSelection(page_val)).
```

It raises the following error:

> TypeError: PageSelection() missing 1 required positional argument: 'page_val'

You need to add one more argument, `controller`. So simply making the above line to this:

```py
nxt = ttk.Button(self, text='Next >', command = lambda:self.PageSelection(controller, page_val)).
```

will fix the problem. Make sure you are adding all the arguments required in your function.

Full code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

LARGE_FONT = ('Verdana', 12)
NORM_FONT = ('Verdana', 10)
SMALL_FONT = ('Verdana', 8)    

class PageSelectionWiz(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)


        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Page Selector")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo, PageThree, PageFour, PageFive, PageSix):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew',padx=20, pady=20)
        self.ShowFrame(StartPage)

    def ShowFrame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def PageSelection(self, controller, page_val):
        page_choice = page_val.get()
        if page_choice == 1:
            controller.ShowFrame(PageOne)
        elif page_choice == 2:
            controller.ShowFrame(PageTwo)
        elif page_choice == 3:
            controller.ShowFrame(PageThree)
        elif page_choice == 4:
            controller.ShowFrame(PageFour)
        elif page_choice == 5:
            controller.ShowFrame(PageFive)
        else:
            controller.ShowFrame(PageSix)

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text='Page Selection', font='LARGE_FONT')
        description = ttk.Label(self, text='Please select a page:')
        label.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky='w',padx=20, pady=5, columnspan=2)
        description.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='w', padx=20, pady=5, columnspan=2)

        page_val = tk.IntVar()

        rad_button1 = ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='Page 1', value=1, variable=page_val)
        rad_button1.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky='sw')
        rad_button2 = ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='Page 2', value=2, variable=page_val)
        rad_button2.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky='sw')
        rad_button3 = ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='Page 3', value=3, variable=page_val)
        rad_button3.grid(row=5, column=2, sticky='sw')
        rad_button4 = ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='Page 4', value=4, variable=page_val)
        rad_button4.grid(row=6, column=2, sticky='sw')
        rad_button5 = ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='Page 5', value=5, variable=page_val)
        rad_button5.grid(row=7, column=2, sticky='sw')
        rad_button6 = ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='Page 6', value=6, variable=page_val)
        rad_button6.grid(row=8, column=2, sticky='sw')

        col_pad = ttk.Label(self, text='').grid(row=9, column=3, pady=25, padx=25)

        quit_button= ttk.Button(self, text='Quit', command = quit)
        quit_button.grid(row=10, column=4, sticky='e')

        nxt = ttk.Button(self, text='Next >', command = lambda: self.PageSelection(controller, page_val))
        nxt.grid(row=10,column=5, sticky='w')


class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

class PageThree(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)


class PageFour(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

class PageFive(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)


class PageSix(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

app = PageSelectionWiz()
app.geometry('640x480-8-8')
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Really appreciate it. I've been stuck on that bit for days and now works perfectly

Comment: @AnnZen Thanks for saying what I wanted to say!